# Datagridview background color for all cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to set background color for all cells when i click on one. 
Sorry am new in winforms

Like on picture

[image]

Like on row 6! All cells has red color on click.

I also try with `DefaultCellStyle` and `DefaultRowStyle` but that is again only for one cell.

Does maybe i need to loop between cells and put for each bg color on select ?

Cab someone give me answer?

Comment: what is `DataGridView.SelectionMode` value? is it acceptable to set it to `FullRowSelect` to achieve you purpose?

Comment: @ASh thanks man that slove my newbie problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
    }
```

or if you want to change background color of complete row then try this

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks and aslo this help me

Comment: If you use such code, you will loose other styles which the cell have, like alignment, fore color, and so on. Also you need to set other rows back color to its original value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to handle any event for this functionality. [`SelectionBackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.selectionbackcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [`DataGridViewCellStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) is for such purpose and it sets the background color used by a `DataGridView` cell when it is selected. It's enough to configure it using designer or code.

Set the desired selection back color for all cells using properties of `DataGridView`:

```
RowsDefaultCellStyle → SelectionBackColor
```

Also you can use:

```
RowTemplate → DefaultCellStyle → SelectionBackColor
```

Then it's enough to set [`SelectionMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `FullRowSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

1. use the datagridview Click event to listen the CurrentRow click.
2. use `DefaultCellStyle` property to set the color.

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but . . .

On the DataGridView there is a `DefaultCellStyle`, inside this there is `SelectionBackColor` and `SelectionForeColor` properties.

The DataGridView uses a style inheritance idea, in case you find that the style you pick is not being applied.